# loop through all elements underneath an element in the doc > then addClass

Tags: jquery

I want to simply detect and loop through all elements that are below a certain element within the document. Then I want to add a class to all the elements that exist below the certain element.

I have started with this, but realize it's completely false.

```
$('div').addClass("below-fold").after('#BelowThisElm');
```

---

No, there is no unique parent element; if there was I wouldn't be trying to do something like this I would just `addClass`.

Answer (score 0):

`.after()` is for adding something after the selected element, it's not used for selecting things. Use a selector that matches all the DIVs below the ID.

```
$("#BelowThisElm div").addClass("below-fold");
```

This operates recursively, it matches the DIVs directly below `#BelowThisElm`, and the ones below them, and so on. If you just want the ones directly below, use

```
$("#BelowThisElm > div").addClass("below-fold");
```

Comment: There is no unique parent element, if there was; this wouldn't be a question I would just addClass?

Answer (score 0):

First we're getting the [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) of the element. Then determine its [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) in the list. Then loop over the siblings and start adding the class if the `key` is bigger than the `index`.

```js
$.each( $("#BelowThisElm").siblings(), function( key, value ) {
  if(key < $("#BelowThisElm").index()) {
      return;
  }
  $(value).addClass("below-fold");
});
```

```css
.below-fold {
    color:#FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Element -2</div>
<div>Element -1</div>
<div>Element 0</div>
<div id="BelowThisElm">Below this element</div>
<div>Element 1</div>
<div>Element 2</div>
<div>Element 3</div>
<div>Element 4</div>
<div>Element 5</div>
```